# Does the content security policy (CSP) get applied before requests are sent to service workers?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, content-security-policy

I'm investigating if a service worker can be used to rewrite certain requests:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (someCondition) {
      event.respondWith(fetch(someOtherUrl));
   }
});
```

What I'm not sure on: can the service worker rewrite requests that would be blocked by the page's Content Security Policy (CSP)?

Comment: Should be easy to test...

Comment: CSP begins to work even BEFORE `fetch` is started (see [pre-Request check](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#img-src-pre-request)). CSP continues to work DURING `fetch` is processed (see [CSP with redirects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-url-to-source-list)). CSP continues to work AFTER 'fetch' is finished (see [Post-Request check](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#img-src-post-request)). After CSP layer a CORS layer check been performed. After that ServiceWorker can get access to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the content security policy (CSP) get applied before requests are sent to service workers?

After a test, it looks like the answer is yes. The CSP gets applied *before* requests are sent to service workers, so it's *not* possible for a service worker to rewrite a request that would originally violate the CSP.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thanks for confirming. Did you validate this with an HTTP response header CSP, or a `<meta>` tag CSP ?

Comment: @ShaiAlon It was with an HTTP response header CSP

Comment: Thanks - I like your experiment. 
Btw, the CSP also get's applied to server-side redirects (like 301).